# Upgrading UE4.19 project to 4.20

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have recently used UE4.19 and I was able to run my project properly. Then I tried to upgrade the project to UE4.20 and keep getting error module are missing, when I try to build them it says to rebuild from source.Below are the error I have been getting from the VS2017 error list.

> The project could not be compiled. Would you like to open it in Visual Studio?
>   Running C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_4.20/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe Development Win64 -Project="C:/Users/HMD GROUP/Documents/Unreal Projects/VRtestNOcalibration 4.20/VRtestNOcalibration.uproject" -TargetType=Editor -Progress -NoHotReloadFromIDE Creating makefile for VRtestNOcalibrationEditor (no existing makefile) Performing full C++ include scan (no include cache file) Using Visual Studio 2017 14.15.26726 toolchain (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726) and Windows 10.0.16299.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10). C:\Users\HMD GROUP\Documents\Unreal Projects\VRtestNOcalibration 4.20\Plugins\UPupilLabsVR\Source\UPupilLabsVR\UPupilLabsVR.Build.cs: warning: Referenced directory 'C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.20\Engine\Source\UPupilLabsVR\Public' does not exist. @progress push 5% Parsing headers for VRtestNOcalibrationEditor Running UnrealHeaderTool "C:\Users\HMD GROUP\Documents\Unreal Projects\VRtestNOcalibration 4.20\VRtestNOcalibration.uproject" "C:\Users\HMD GROUP\Documents\Unreal Projects\VRtestNOcalibration 4.20\Intermediate\Build\Win64\VRtestNOcalibrationEditor\Development\VRtestNOcalibrationEditor.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -installed Reflection code generated for VRtestNOcalibrationEditor in 9.9373837 seconds @progress pop Building 11 actions with 8 processes... @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 0% @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 9% [1/11] PCLaunch.rc @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 18% [2/11] PCLaunch.rc @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 27% [3/11] SharedPCH.Engine.cpp @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 36% [4/11] VRtestNOcalibration.cpp @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 45% [5/11] dummyctoopenvisual.cpp @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 55% [6/11] UE4Editor-VRtestNOcalibration.lib Creating library C:\Users\HMD GROUP\Documents\Unreal Projects\VRtestNOcalibration 4.20\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\VRtestNOcalibration\UE4Editor-VRtestNOcalibration.lib and object C:\Users\HMD GROUP\Documents\Unreal Projects\VRtestNOcalibration 4.20\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\VRtestNOcalibration\UE4Editor-VRtestNOcalibration.exp @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 64% [7/11] Module.UPupilLabsVR.gen.cpp C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winnt.h(584): warning C4005: 'TEXT': macro redefinition c:\program files\epic games\ue_4.20\engine\source\runtime\core\public\HAL/Platform.h(884): note: see previous definition of 'TEXT' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7542): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_TH2' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7548): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS1' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7553): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_TH2' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7557): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_TH2' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7564): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS2' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7574): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS2' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7578): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_TH2' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7583): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS3' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7777): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS2' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(12249): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS3' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(12266): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS3' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(12285): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS2' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(12404): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS3' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Users\HMD GROUP\Documents\Unreal Projects\VRtestNOcalibration 4.20\Plugins\UPupilLabsVR\Source\ThirdParty\msgpack\Includes\msgpack/predef/other/endian.h(151): error C4668: 'MSGPACK_ARCH_AMD64' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/array_ref.hpp(262): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/array_ref.hpp(267): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/map.hpp(204): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/map.hpp(210): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector.hpp(98): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector.hpp(103): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector_char.hpp(35): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector_char.hpp(40): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector_char.hpp(48): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector_char.hpp(53): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector_unsigned_char.hpp(35): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector_unsigned_char.hpp(40): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector_unsigned_char.hpp(48): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector_unsigned_char.hpp(53): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' @progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 73% [8/11] Module.UPupilLabsVR.cpp C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winnt.h(584): warning C4005: 'TEXT': macro redefinition c:\program files\epic games\ue_4.20\engine\source\runtime\core\public\HAL/Platform.h(884): note: see previous definition of 'TEXT' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7542): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_TH2' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7548): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS1' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7553): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_TH2' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7557): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_TH2' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7564): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS2' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7574): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS2' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7578): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_TH2' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7583): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS3' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(7777): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS2' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(12249): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS3' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(12266): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS3' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(12285): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS2' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winioctl.h(12404): error C4668: 'WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_RS3' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' C:\Users\HMD GROUP\Documents\Unreal Projects\VRtestNOcalibration 4.20\Plugins\UPupilLabsVR\Source\ThirdParty\msgpack\Includes\msgpack/predef/other/endian.h(151): error C4668: 'MSGPACK_ARCH_AMD64' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/array_ref.hpp(262): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/array_ref.hpp(267): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/map.hpp(204): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/map.hpp(210): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector.hpp(98): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector.hpp(103): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector_char.hpp(35): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector_char.hpp(40): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector_char.hpp(48): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector_char.hpp(53): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector_unsigned_char.hpp(35): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector_unsigned_char.hpp(40): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector_unsigned_char.hpp(48): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' c:\users\hmd group\documents\unreal projects\vrtestnocalibration 4.20\plugins\upupillabsvr\source\thirdparty\msgpack\includes\msgpack/v1/adaptor/vector_unsigned_char.hpp(53): error C4668: 'GNUC' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif' ERROR: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: C:\Users\HMD GROUP\Documents\Unreal Projects\VRtestNOcalibration 4.20\Plugins\UPupilLabsVR\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\UPupilLabsVR\UE4Editor-UPupilLabsVR.lib (see ../Programs/UnrealBuildTool/Log.txt for full exception trace) Total build time: 59.05 seconds (Parallel executor: 0.00 seconds)

Comment: I think you'll have a better chance of getting help in [the UE forums](https://forums.unrealengine.com).

Comment: thanks for he suggestion, @molbdnilo I've posted there as well but still can't fix the problem.

Comment: Windows and all platform code is already included.  And wrapped in a platform safe wrapper..  These are called FPLatform::XXXXXX..  That handle platform specific features.  You should never Include any platform headers directly in your code.

Answer (score 6):

If you've included the windows headers directly, replace:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

with

```
#include "Windows/MinWindows.h"
```

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/811727/

Note that if you do need to include a specific windows header and you for some reason need to include it directly which is causing this issue, ensure that you specify the following directive *before* the include directive:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/813258/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding some additional header files along with `<Windows.h>`.
For me the macros errors were gone by adding these header files.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#include <comutil.h>
```